# React native creating .tsx project by default

Tags: javascript, react-native, tsx

`npx react-native init AwesomeProject`
Create .tsx project by default. I need to create .js project.
Do you know the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react native is shifting more and more to typescript to make dev easier - please also see the [official blog](https://reactnative.dev/blog) and last posts

You can though easily get it back to js by changing the tsx to js and deleting the additional typescript content, normally takes less than 5 mins.